# PyCharm warning for PyMissingConstructor in subclass __init__ but superclass has no __init__

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, python-sphinx

I'm sublcassing a numpy.ndarray following their [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) on how to do that.

At the same time, I'm familiarizing myself with Sphinx and was trying to document the attributes for my subclass. These attribute are defined in `__new__` since the [ndarray does not have an `__init__`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.htmlg). Unfortunately even using the `:special-members:` flag is used in `.. autoclass::`.

To overcome this I added an `__init__` to my sublcass, but the PyCharm linter throws:

```
Call to __init__ of super class is missed
```

I figured I could just add in a `super().__init__()` but that throws:

```
Parameter 'shape' unfilled
```

But if you pass a parameter that meets that criteria, it throws:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes 0 parameters
```

In the end I just end up suppressing the PyCharm linter as such:

```
# noinspection PyMissingConstructor
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

But if the super class does not have an `__init__`, why is the linter throwing this warning?

Comment: PyCharm's linter doesn't strike me as particularly intelligent. I don't believe it actually takes into account whether the parent class overrode `__init__` or uses the inherited method; it just notices that *you* seemed to have forgotten to invoke the parent's `__init__`.

Comment: @chepner Do you know of a way to suppress PyCharm linter warnings without adding in the comment?

Comment: Aside from not using PyCharm (my personal preference)? :) No.

Comment: I agree with @chepner (first comment, not the one about the preference - I quite like PyCharm ;), though I would file a bug for PyCharm. In my experience, the folks at JetBrains are quite responsive.

Comment: Is there a problem with Sphinx?

Comment: @mzjn No problem, its just related to documenting and I state why I have to use the `__init__` since Sphinx doesnt allow you to document instance attributes via `__new__`.

Comment: @chepner I've been meaning to ask, what do you use if not pycharm?

Comment: `vim`; I'm not big on IDEs in general.